# How can I return response from RabbitMQ producer to RestController?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-rabbit

I have got two Spring Boot application. First one is REST application. The REST one is communicating with second application through RabbitMQ message queue. I'm sending a request to method with the `@GetMapping("/")` and this method producing a message to example-queue. A method with `@RabbitListener(queues = {"example-queue"})` taking the message and create a object at database. Now, how can I send my response (saved object) to the method with `@GetMapping("/")`? I need a response from consumer to ResponseEntity.ok();. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code you already have? Since messaging is asynchronous WITHOUT response values i doubt what you are trying to achieve is possible. You can use a hibernate hook on postPersist to send a new message or something similar.

Comment: it's a little difficult because you need to way to wait on an async event inside your `@GetMapping` method. You would need to come up with code that can do that by using e.g. a `CompletableFuture` that is stored in a map under a request id and once the response for that request comes in that future is completed by the `RabbitListener`. You also might want to add a timeout since most web request don't expect request s to take forever. If it takes to long return a request id and let the client check again later if the request got a reply

Answer (score 2):

Just see if you can make the interaction with RabbitMQ consumer as a request-reply pattern.

The `@RabbitListener` can just return your object and be marked with a `@SendTo`. This way the framework will look into a `replyTo` property of the request message.

On the producer side you can just use an `AmqpTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#request-reply

Comment: Is there any example for usage? I couldn't make it actually.

Comment: Take a look into this one, please: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-spring-amqp.html